# MySQL: subqueries (basic)

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

Im new at SQL and trying to create a basic subquery. I need to find the difference between the avg age in Manager and avg age in Trainee.

Title is one column- Manager or Trainee 
Age is one column, all within the same table.

Would i use two subqueries to do something like:

```
Select manager_age - trainee_age
from book1
(select avg(age) as manager_age from book1 where title = "manager")
```

and another subquery:

```
(select avg(age) as manager_age from book1 where title = "trainee")
```

Im not sure how to do two subqueries in one query or if I should do this another way like a join? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
create table book1(title varchar(50), age integer) ;

insert into book1 values('Trainee', 10);
insert into book1 values('Trainee', 20);
insert into book1 values('Manager', 30);
insert into book1 values('Manager', 40);
insert into book1 values('Manager', 50);

select * from book1;

select m.m_age - t.t_age from (
(select title as m_title, avg(age) as m_age
 from book1 where title = 'Manager') m, 
(select title as t_title, avg(age) as t_age
 from book1 where title = 'Trainee') t);
```